# Marcar checkbox según valor en un campo y de forma independiente

Tags: vba, ms-access

tengo una base de datos de especies en el que se contempla, entre otras cosas, un campo para indicar si están protegidos por el catálogo X y qué tipo de protección tendría (así que no es un campo booleano).
Quería crear un informe en el que aparezca un checkbox que se marque si la especie está protegida por lo que aplico el siguiente código al cargar el informe:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
If Me.[CAT_NAC] = "<Null>" Then
    CAT_NAC_VER.Value = False
Else
    CAT_NAC_VER.Value = True
End If
End Sub
```

Pero me hace la validación para el primero de los registros y el resto heredan el mismo resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo tendría que hacer para que el resultado sera independiente a cada registro?

Comment: No recuerdo como Access compara los valores NULL, puedes probar con `If Me.[CAT_NAC] = Null` (sin comillas) o bien con `If Me.[CAT_NAC] = ""`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no es el fallo, en el programa en el que traté los datos antes de pasarlo al Access los valores nulos los convirtió en una String con el valor "<Null>". Debería de haberlo aclarado antes disculpen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo tienes que modificar en la consulta que alimente a este informe/report, no en el propio report. Si lo haces desde VBA en tiempo de ejecución, solamente afectará al registro actual (Current Record) y no a todos.

No sé como tendrás organizados los datos, pero he diseñado un ejemplo sencillo para ver si te puede servir.

Como tu valor nulo no es un Nulo Real, sino de texto `<Null>`, en la consulta te puedes hacer un campo calculado que te devuelva Verdadero/Falso dependiendo de si el texto es `<Null>` o no.

Yo he hecho esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sobre esta tabla, he hecho una consulta, en la que he creado un campo calculado que me devuelve un valor booleano(verdadero/falso) dependiendo de si el texto es `<Null>` o no.

Mi consulta tras ejecutarla devuelve esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código SQL de mi consulta es así:

```
SELECT Tabla1.Campo1Texto, Tabla1.CampoNulo, CBool(IIf([CampoNulo]="<Null>",True,False)) AS MI_BOOLEAN
FROM Tabla1;
```

Y una vez que ya tengo una consulta que me devuelve lo que quiero, creo el informe/report basado en esa consulta. Lo configuro para ver únicamente el campo de texto, y el campo booleano, el cual he asociado a una casilla checkbox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, devuelve justo lo que estás buscando. **No necesitas VBA para esto**.

Espero que puedas adaptar esto a tu base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servidor perfectamente.